# SAP ADS error when big PDF document created

Tags: pdf-generation, sap-basis, netweaver

I get an error in system ABP (ABAP instance) in transaction which calls ADS system to create a big PDF document.

Everything works correctly if the document is small.

I read SAP notes and run check configuration (program `FP_TEST_00`). It is ok.

How can I associate current user activity in ABAP with errors which I see by NWA on JAVA instance (tracert log)? For example I have 100 users who requested a PDF at the same time.

I don't understand if this is error connect with activity dedicated user or not.

Thank you!

Comment: `in transaction which calls ADS system` is this standard or custom transaction?

Comment: This is custom(Z) transaction .

Comment: nobody knows what's going on under the hood of your Z transaction, too little input. Also, you have several questions in one: NWA related and performance related, each one requires a separate question.

Comment: The problem going from ADS instance. How can i debug java? Zprogram received only error from ads. Test program FP_TEST_00 works ok.

Comment: "How to activate ADS trace in NW 7.0x [Video]" was made. I see that exception com.adobe.ProcessingException was raised, but who and why reason of this - no information

Comment: there seems to be a limitation to how large documents can be created with ADS: https://help.sap.com/saphelp_em92/helpdata/en/1f/d9bc3854564800be3a220912428288/frameset.htm. It looks like the issue might be either processing time or the maximum allowed request size of ICM (kernel parameer icm/HTTP/max_request_size_KB ).